# Pass product object to javscript

Tags: php, javascript

I am getting a product object in php and I want to pass it to JavaScript.

This is the php code:

```
<?php

// Add custom Theme Functions here
// 

//gg stands for Gear Guide
function gear_guide_product_view( $atts ) {

    //Get Ids from shortcode
    $gg_attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '0'
    ), $atts );

    $gg_products_ids = Array();
    $gg_products = Array();

    //Push ID's into array
    if ( strpos( $gg_attributes['id'], ',' ) !== false ) {
        echo 'Multiple ID\'s!';
        $gg_products_ids = explode( ',', $gg_attributes['id'] );
    } else {
        echo 'Just one Id!';
        $gg_products_ids[] = $gg_attributes['id'];
    }
    echo var_dump($gg_products_ids);

    //Get product by ID's
    foreach ( $gg_products_ids as $gg_product_id ) {
        $gg_product = trim( $gg_product_id, ' ' );
        array_push($gg_products, wc_get_product( $gg_product ));
    }
    echo var_dump( $gg_products );
    wp_register_script( 'load_product_info' , '/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/js/test.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'load_product_info' );
    wp_localize_script( 'load_product_info' , 'products' , $gg_products);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );

add_shortcode( 'fsg' , 'gear_guide_product_view' );
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function load_product_info() {
    console.log(products);
}
load_product_info();
```

When I am `echo`ing `gg_products` the variable looks good but in the `console.log` I am getting an array containing two empty objects.

Does anyone sees why is it happening?

If more information is needed tell me and I will do my best to provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
 wp_localize_script( 'load_product_info' , 'products' , $gg_products);
```

with
(EDITED ->wp_localize_script() accepts an array as 3rd par.)

```
 wp_localize_script( 'load_product_info' , 'products' , array('current_products'=>json_encode($gg_products ) ) );
```

transforming the php object into a json string and building an array .

Then in the js file convert the string into a js object with JSON.parse

```
function load_product_info() {
  var _products=JSON.parse( products )
  console.log( _products.current_products );
}
load_product_info();
```

Comment: Already tried it, this is what I'm getting in the console: `Array [ {}, {} ]`

Comment: Something I noticed is when I am `echo`ing `json_encode( $gg_products )` I am getting the same `[ {}, {} ]` result

Comment: The 3rd argument in `wp_localize_script()` needs to be an array, not a json encoded string.

Comment: use `wp_localize_script( 'load_product_info' , 'products' , array('my_data'=>json_encode($gg_products ) );` converting i an array the last parameter

Comment: Do I have to json encode the array in order to pass it?

Comment: @AndreaSomovigo I just tried your code and I am getting an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: console.log(products) before JSON.parse and see the result. There will be strings that must be replaced (quotes, dblquotes)

Comment: did you try  console.log(products) ?